# Pressing `up` to get the previous command in a tty on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, command-history

I've installed Ubuntu Server 10.10, and when I press <kbd>up</kbd> in a terminal nothing happens. Using Ubuntu Desktop it gave me the previous command that I ran.

How can I make it do this in Ubuntu Server as well?

Comment: It should just happen... Are you sure you have some command history for it to repeat? Do you have a file named `~/.bash_history`?

Comment: The keyboard mapping was indeed incorrect. I fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the up arrow key work in other contexts? It sounds like you might have the keyboard mapped wrong, bash history should be pretty easy.

Comment: (I moved this answer from a comment to an answer, it was a long shot so I figured I wouldn't clutter the answer space, but since it came out right... :)